# Reporting on code execution and design patterns?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, design-patterns, logging, report

First of all I wanted to thank all of you for your continuous contributions to the Stack Overflow community! I've been a member of Stack Overflow for years and have come to rely on your input more so than any other source online. Though I try to participate and answer members' questions whenever I can, every once in a while I find myself stuck and in need of help.

Speaking of which I have an unusual code problem. I am writing an API library in C# that needs to be able to be called from WPF/Windows Forms application, but also from within Unit Test code.

The issue is that I need to be able to report (in Excel) on whether each method of the library executed properly when the API is called from within a WPF/windows forms application, along some other metadata and optionally a return type.

When the code is consumed within Unit Tests I don't really care about the reporting, but I do need to be able to produce an Assert on whether the API call executed properly or not.

For instance, if in a Unit Test we have an `Test Initialize` portion, one of the API calls may be to create a Domain User for the test method to use. Another one may also create a Domain Group, so that the user has proper group membership.

To accomodate the consumption of the API from WPF/WinForms, I've been rewriting every function in the API to return a `OperationStep` type, with the hopes that when all API calls have executed I would have an `IEnumerable<OperationStep>` which I can write to a CSV file.

So the question is is there an easier way of achieving what I have done so far? The reporting is extremely tedious and time consuming to code, considering that the API library consists of hundreds of similar methods. Samples are described bellow:

```
OperationStep<PrincipalContext> createDomainConnectionStep = DomainContext.Current.GetPrincipalContext(settings.DomainInfo);
OperationStep<UserPrincipal> createDomainUserStep = DomainContext.Current.CreateUser(createDomainConnectionStep.Context, settings.TestAccountInfo.Username, settings.TestAccountInfo.Password);
OperationStep<GroupPrincipal> createDomainGroupStep = DomainContext.Current.CreateGroup(createDomainConnectionStep.Context, settings.TestAccountInfo.UserGrupName);
```

Where the DomainContext is a singleton object whose functionality is to connect to the domain controller and create a user, group, and associate the user to a group.

Note that both the second and the third method call require the output of the first, and therefore warranting the need for having the `public T Context` within the `OperationResult` object as described bellow.

The `OperationStep` object consists of the following properties which are inherited by the `IOperation` interface with the exception of the `public T Context`.

```
public class OperationStep<T> : IOperation
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Denotes the Logical Name of the current operation
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Denotes the stage of execution of the current operation: Setup, Execution, Validation, Cleanup 
    /// </summary>
    public OperationStage Stage { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Denotes whether the test step completed properly or failed.
    /// </summary>
    public OperationResult Result { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Denotes the return type of the test method.
    /// </summary>
    public T Context { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Denotes any other relevant information about the test step
    /// </summary>
    public string Description { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// If the test step result is failed, this should have the stack trace and the error message.
    /// </summary>
    public string Error { get; set; }
}
```

The method calls themselves are a bit bloated and tedious but here is a sample.

```
public class DomainContext
{
    private static volatile DomainContext currentContext;
    private static object synchronizationToken = new object();

    /// <summary>
    /// default ctor.
    /// </summary>
    private DomainContext() { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves the Current DomainContext instance.
    /// </summary>
    public static DomainContext Current
    {
        get
        {
            if (currentContext == null)
            {
                lock (synchronizationToken)
                {
                    if (currentContext == null)
                    {
                        currentContext = new DomainContext();
                    }
                }
            }
            return currentContext;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Establishes a connection to the domain.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="domainInfo"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public OperationStep<PrincipalContext> GetPrincipalContext(DomainInfo domainInfo)
    {
        OperationStep<PrincipalContext> result = new OperationStep<PrincipalContext>();
        result.Name = "Establish Connection to Active Directory";
        result.Result = OperationResult.Success;
        result.Stage = OperationStage.Setup;
        result.Description = string.Format("Domain Name: {0}, Default Containter: {1}", domainInfo.FQDN, domainInfo.Container);

        try
        {
            ContextType contextType = this.GetContextType(domainInfo.DomainType);
            PrincipalContext principalContext;

            try
            {
                principalContext = new PrincipalContext(contextType, domainInfo.FQDN, domainInfo.Container);
            }
            catch
            {
                throw new Exception("Unable to establish connection to Active Directory with the specified connection options.");
            }

            if (principalContext != null)
            {
                bool authenticationResult = principalContext.ValidateCredentials(domainInfo.Username, domainInfo.Password);

                if (!authenticationResult)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Unable to authenticate domain admin user to Active Directory.");
                }

                result.Context = principalContext;
                result.Result = OperationResult.Success;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            result.Error = ex.Message;
            result.Result = OperationResult.Failure;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

When all method calls have executed theoreticaly I should have an `IEnumerable<IOperation>` which in the case of a win form I can write in a csv file (to be viewed in MS Excel) or in the case of a unit test I can simply omit the extra info and ignore (other than the method executed successively and the `T Context` property).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly - all that `OperationStep`s are here only for logging. Then why not enable simple .NET logging? Log needed info where it is convenient for you. You can use `TraceSource` with `DelimetedTraceListener` to write to .csv file. More than that. You can move logging logic to `Strategy` class and override its logging methods in your unit test so that instead of logging you call Assert methods.